# Is there a problem if i use sequelize with postgres?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.3

when i create the nodejs projcet using sequelize its shows warning like that?

```
(node:29688) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'prototype' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
app running on port 4040
(node:29688) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'schema' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:29688) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tableName' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

What's the error describing and what's the issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to update surge to the latest version:

```
sudo npm i -g surge
```